# Add column to a dataframe based on multiple conditions (values based on another dataframe)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. First one represent a certain transaction from a `client` at a praticular `date`. The second dataframe shows to which `group` every `client` was assigned to.

df1

```
client  date
1       01.01.2020
2       01.01.2020
3       02.01.2020
4       03.01.2020
```

df2

```
client group beginning   end
1      11    01.01.2019  NaN
2      12    01.01.2019  01.07.2019
2      11    02.07.2019  01.02.2020
2      13    02.02.2020  NaN
3      13    01.08.2019  NaN
4      12    01.09.2019  31.01.2020
4      14    01.02.2020  NaN
```

I need to add the third column to `df1` which will show to which `group` the `client` was assigned to at the transaction `date`. So the output expected is like this:

```
client  date        group
1       01.01.2020  11
2       01.01.2020  11
3       02.01.2020  13
4       03.01.2020  12
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas `merge` with multiple columns in the `on` parameter:

```
df_output = df1.merge(df2[['client','group','beginning']],how='left',left_on=['client','date'],right_on=['client','beginning'])
```

Comment: I think it works only if date and beginning are the same.

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted.

Comment: I just read your question again, you want to match them to either beginning or end date, right?

Comment: The `date` parameter should be in between `beginning` and `end`. Basically a `client`  can be in different `groups` at different periods of time, so I need to add `group` field that is actual on transaction `date`